# Convert one type to another

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type Popups = {
  'createUserDialog': TCreateUserDialogProperties,
  'updateUserDialog': TUpdateUserDialogProperties
};
```

I would like to convert this type to:

```
type Something = {
  name: 'createUserDialog',
  properties: TCreateUserDialogProperties
} | {
  name: 'updateUserDialog',
  properties: TUpdateUserDialogProperties
};
```

How I can do this, I've tried this solution:

```
type Something = {
  [K in keyof Popups]: {
    name: K,
    properties: Popups[K]
  }
};
```

but it is incorrect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much got it. I think [this is what you want](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgwgJwgQ2BAqgZwggIgS2QBsB7AcwAUETIFh8JMoBeKAbwCgBfDj0SWOjAATVBmx5CpStVr1GLdt179oFGgFcwTVpyhQA5AGMkYrDgLFyBgFyxEKNOclWZNHPMwAaDvoNbRJwlLaVtBETNgqXIqdzoGTG4AbhVwaABlEgBbCGAAC3wAOzJFPSgAbQBpKCKoAGsIEBIAMyh1MC1MAF07Mv1C5By7Sp99fTBZDwS7ds6qrt8oHi5yhqbW2e0upKA):

```
type Something = {
  [K in keyof Popups]: {
    name: K,
    properties: Popups[K]
  }
}[keyof Popups];
```